# Nonhomogeneous system of ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have been working on this problem for hours now and I don't know how to finish it
$$
    X'=    \begin{bmatrix}
        -2 & -2 \\
        4 & -2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}X\ +\ 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3t \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\
$$
 I have managed to eigenvalues and eigenvectors, which I got 
$\lambda=-2+(\sqrt2)i\  and \lambda=-2-(\sqrt2)i$ and then I managed to solve up to here 
$$
    C_1e^{-2t}\begin{bmatrix}
        -\sqrt2sin(2\sqrt2t) \\
        2cos(2\sqrt2t) \\
        \end{bmatrix}\ +\ 
   C_2e^{-2t}\begin{bmatrix}
        \sqrt2cos(2\sqrt2t) \\
        2sin(2\sqrt2t) \\
        \end{bmatrix}\
$$
Some help on to what to do next would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: How did they get $y^{''}+y=cos(2t)$? I understand where the cosine comes from but not the $y^{''}$ but thank you for the link.

Comment: ,Your general solution should be$C_1*e^{-2t}\small\begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt{0.5}\sin{(2\sqrt{2}t)}\\\cos{(2\sqrt{2}t)}\end{pmatrix}+C_2*e^{-2t}\small\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{0.5}\cos{(2\sqrt{2}t)}\\\sin{(2\sqrt{2}t)}\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give a quick solution.

Let us make a guess
\begin{align}
X(t) = w + tv
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
v = A(w+tv) = Aw + tAv +f  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ v-Aw - tAv = f
\end{align}
which mean
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2
\end{pmatrix}
-
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & -2\\
4 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
w_1\\
w_2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
t\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & -2\\
4 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2
\end{pmatrix}
=t
\begin{pmatrix}
-3\\
0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Solving for $v, w$ yields 
\begin{align}
v=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \
w =
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{1}{12}\\
-\frac{1}{6}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
X(t) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{1}{12}+\frac{t}{2}\\
-\frac{1}{6}+t
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
is a particular solution.

Comment: is the general solution given in the original post is correct? In my comment, I have given my solution. which is correct?

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod They are the same.